# The official docker image postgres is not running under debian buster

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, dockerhub

When I run

```
$ docker run --name some-postgres5 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
c525b8eef01acf2e998eb877fe7ad8a4236c7e5c8c3a8139722d77264b98c51b
```

then the container is not running

```
$ docker ps -f id=c525b8eef01acf2e998eb877fe7ad8a4236c7e5c8c3a8139722d77264b98c51b
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

$ docker logs c525b8eef01acf2e998eb877fe7ad8a4236c7e5c8c3a8139722d77264b98c51b
popen failure: Cannot allocate memory
initdb: error: program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was not found in the same directory as "/usr/lib/postgresql/16/bin/initdb"
```

When I use the bullseye variant, the container is running:

```
$ docker run --name some-postgres6 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres:bullseye
39d42eb30f1e23a7f1da15fc8c433508f44f9e67acf202b99d1838d010530eab

$ docker ps -f id=39d42eb30f1e23a7f1da15fc8c433508f44f9e67acf202b99d1838d010530eab
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
39d42eb30f1e        postgres:bullseye   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        5432/tcp            some-postgres6
```

And when I run it on debian unstable, then it is running also.

I don't know why it is not running under debian buster.

Version is:

```
$ dpkg -l 'docker.io'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version                   Architecture Description
+++-==============-=========================-============-=================================
ii  docker.io      18.09.1+dfsg1-7.1+deb10u3 amd64        Linux container runtime
```

Maybe stackoverflow is not the right place to complain about this, so besides the obvious question how to fix this issue, it would be interesting where to complain about this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior.  Maybe the image you have labeled `postgres` is the wrong image.  `docker pull postgres`.

Comment: My image id is 75b7bff7c3ad . I reinstalled it, same behaviour.

Comment: First line of your container log is `popen failure: Cannot allocate memory`. The container runs out of memory.

Comment: I repeated the procedure on an fresh new installation of debian-10.13.0-amd64-netinst.iso . I get the exact same error.